# Layout problems after upgrading to Android 7

Tags: android-layout, androiddesignsupport, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

On every Android version before Android 7 Nougat, my application worked perfectly on every resolution and every phone. After upgrading to 7, on every phone, everything is messed up, pictures are being rendered incorrectly, scroll views are not working etc.. And i can't find any issue in mt code.
Could anyone answer what changes about that are made in the update and how it could be fixed?